# Simplify this method with recursion

Tags: php, recursion

I need to simplify this method with a recursion to get rid of duplicate business logic but I cannot figure out how to do this:

```
public function compute()
{
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
        $ret[] = array($item);
    }
    foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
        foreach ($this->_items as $item2) {
            $tmp = array($item, $item2);
            if (count($tmp) === count(array_unique($tmp))) {
                $ret[] = $tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
        foreach ($this->_items as $item2) {
            foreach ($this->_items as $item3) {
                $tmp = array($item, $item2, $item3);
                if (count($tmp) === count(array_unique($tmp))) {
                    $ret[] = $tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

EDIT:

This method is supposed to return all combinations of array elements, so if you have array like:

```
[a, b, c]
```

It will return:

```
[
    [a],
    [b],
    [c],
    [a, b],
    [a, c],
    [b, a],
    [b, c],
    [a, b, c],
    [a, c, b],
    [b, a, c],
    [b, c, a],
    [c, a, b],
    [c, b, a]
]
```

Comment: What's the goal of your code?

Comment: It would nice for you to `print_r($this->items)` and also `print_r($ret)` so that i can understand input and expected output ....

Comment: @Ofir Baruch I have added goal of this code to my question.

Comment: @Baba I have added goal of this code to my question.

Answer (score 2):

For your computation there is no need of recursion to streamline that what you call business logic here. At least not at first. It's already enough to move the duplicate code into a function of it's own and then do the processing.

I also suggest this as first step because of the order of execution you have here:

```
public function compute()
{

    $ret = array();

    foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
        $ret[] = array($item);
    }

    $each = function(array $tmp) use (&$ret) {
        if (count($tmp) === count(array_unique($tmp))) {
            $ret[] = $tmp;
        }
    }

    foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
        foreach ($this->_items as $item2) {
            $each(array($item, $item2));
        }
    }

    foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
        foreach ($this->_items as $item2) {
            foreach ($this->_items as $item3) {
                $each(array($item, $item2, $item3));
            }
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: I think an answer on the site exists for that. Right now I can not look into it, maybe later. But if you search a bit, chances are that you find it.